# Is Drupal 6 is compatible with PHP 7?

Tags: drupal-6, php-7

I have a website in Drupal 6 version. But now I wanted to change the server and php version to 7.

So just wanted to confirm that is Drupal 6 is compatible with PHP 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it is not a good idea : https://www.drupal.org/node/2735435

Drupal 6 support was dropped before php 7 release and if you add to that the contribued modules wich might be totally incompatible, the cost of going to php 7 will not be light.

It might be easier to go from drupal 6 to 7 (not much changed btw these 2 versions) or if you have more time to remake your site go for drupal 8 (drupal 7 and 8 are compatible php7, drupal 7 might have some contribued modules that are not compatibles).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

There are plans to make Drupal 6 compatible with PHP 7. See [PHP 7 branch of the d6lts repository](https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/tree/php-7) and the issue on github: [PHP 7 branch - Plan for release #8](https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/issues/8).

See also the announcement [Drupal 6 in the year 2020 (and with PHP 7 support!)](https://www.mydropwizard.com/blog/drupal-6-year-2020-and-php-7-support) of mydropwizard.com, official D6 LTS supporter:

> Today, I'm happy to announce that we'll be extending our Drupal 6 Long-Term Support until at least February 2020!

Comment: Note that the php7 branch was merged into the main drupal6 long term support repository, so now use https://github.com/d6lts/drupal/