# Drupal 6 site migration issue in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, ubuntu-16.04

We have a web server with Ubuntu 12.04. we are running a drupal website in this server and we used PHP 5.3 on this server.

As part of server migration, I am planning to up a new Ubuntu 16.04 server with latest PHP 7.2, After migrating above specified Drupal application into it, We are getting a white screen when we try to access this site.Our developer says that it is because of some of the drupal core functionality is not working with new PHP 7.2, because some of the functionality that used D6 is deprecated in Latest PHP. So we need a Drupal version upgrade to 8. System upgrade to D6 will require more work. So can anyone suggest any alternative options other than Drupal version upgrade.

Also we are using php memcached in old server, PHP 7.2 is not provided memcached

Comment: Jumping from php5.3 to php7.2 is a huge decision (better, yet tricky)
I would suggest you to switch to php5.6 and check if everything works, then try php7.  
in php7 lots of things changed and removed, and distance from php5.3 - php7 changelog is huge to overlook.  
I know very little of drupal, but if D6 uses some removed extension like mysql_* then you have no way other than upgrading your version.
Good Luck.  
edit: [looks like its not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404126/5527461)

Comment: All i can say is that you shouldn't be using Drupal 6 anymore. This version is no longer offically supported and was never built to run on PHP7 since support has ended. Either upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8, or downgrade PHP version to 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

Even Drupal 7 has issues with PHP 7. The core should work, but lot of 3rd party modules won't and I wouldn't recommend running Drupal 7 site on PHP 7.

For Drupal 6 situation is most likely even worse so if you don't want to end up patching manually large number of modules and D6 core I would advise you not to do this. Try to provide older PHP version or this can easy become never ending nightmare.